# Max-height not working as expected on Android stock browser

Tags: android, html, css

On Android 4.0.4, stock browser, I'm having trouble setting an image's maximum height. At the moment it renders outside of its container.

**HTML**

```
<div class="dualBlock">
    <div class="dualImage col-postImage">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/600" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dualBlock {
    width:80%;
    margin:50px auto;
}
div.dualImage {
    max-height:300px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red;
}
div.dualImage img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/QkEtq/1/

This works fine in chrome and renders as expected, the problem only occurs on Android stock browser.

If I define a height for `.dualImage`, say 300px it works. Why does Android only accept a defined height and how can I get this to work on its stock browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
div.dualImage img {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```